# Testing multiple login sessions in browsers

Tags: session, testing

I have a website which have many login user types. Say admin A, user B, owner C... etc. I was trying to open up normal browsers for A operations. Chrome incognito for B. And maybe Safari for C but this gets really messy because I had to switch from window to window...

Is there a standard way to test multiple login users?

Comment: Well, If you're restricting yourself to manual testing, there's an extension for Firefox called Multifox.

Comment: kk lemme check first. thanks